Write Operations on External Tables in Databricks
I am trying to understand what kind of write operations are supported on Unity Catalog external tables created in Databricks.
So, an example query to create an external table would look as follows:
CREATE TABLE ext_tbl
USING CSV
OPTIONS (
  header "true",
  inferSchema "true"
)
LOCATION 'abfss://<container>@<adls-account>/path/to/data.csv'

Is it possible to write (append, overwrite or upsert) data to these tables?
A simple INSERT INTO query resulted in the following error:
AnalysisException: Cannot insert into abfss://<container>@<adls-account>/path/to/data.csv, as it is a file instead of a directory.

I also tried new_df.write.format('csv').mode('<mode>').saveAsTable("ext_iris_csv"), which result in the following error:
Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation."

Is there some way I can write data to external tables? I have data in other formats as well  such as partitioned Parquet datasets.

Two things: for the first error you are specifying the file name with location and it should always be a directory path without any extension. And other thing is only insert operations are supported on non delta format external tables and you will have to specify the path option to save it as external table.

When you create an external table in Databricks, you are defining metadata for an existing object stored in Unity Catalog,which enables you to query the data using SQL.
When you query an external table, Databricks retrieves the data from the external storage location defined in the table's metadata.
For example I have mounted the ADLS & created external table:
%sql
CREATE  TABLE  IF  NOT  EXISTS  hive_metastore.default.cust USING csv OPTIONS (path  "/mnt/raw/new/dds.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True)

ID  Name
1   dilip
2   raj
3   Narayan

And I have tried to insert record to the table & recevied the same like you:
%sql
INSERT INTO hive_metastore.default.cust VALUES (4, 'John')
AnalysisException: Cannot insert into dbfs:/mnt/raw/new/dds.csv, as it is a file instead of a directory.

To perform inserts, updates, or deletes on an external Delta table, you need to use the Delta Lake commands.
adls_path = "abfss://folder02@lamborginistg.dfs.core.windows.net/new/delta-table"
df.write.format("delta").save(adls_path)

Inserting  record
new_data = [("David", 40), ("Eva", 25)]
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_data, schema=columns)
new_df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(adls_path)

Results:
df_delta = spark.read.format("delta").load(adls_path)
df_delta.show()


+-----+---+
| Name|Age|
+-----+---+
|David| 40|
|Alice| 34|
|Cathy| 29|
|  Bob| 45|
|  Eva| 25|
+-----+---+


Reference: Do external tables automatically receive external updates?

When using external Delta tables, my experience has been that it is not required to use paths. I can do new_df.write.format('delta').mode("append").saveAsTable('cust') without an issue. I am more interested in how this would work for tables of other formats.

The way you are creating the external table using the sql script looks good but only the issue is that the location value that you are providing should always be a directory and not file.
Second you can only perform insert operations on the non-delta format external tables.
Third the way you are trying to create the external table using dataframe api is not correct because in order to create the external table you need to explicitly specify the path option and specify the value for that path option.
If you want to understand more details about it a good reference document link: https://medium.com/@sundarleads/create-external-tables-using-file-format-delta-parquet-json-csv-f1d00f967170

Hi Nikunj, external tables can be created by pointing to a file or a directory. There is no restriction that has been placed on this. The DataFrame API code that I am using here is not to create a table, but rather my attempt at writing to an existing table. I am already aware that inserts (appends) by including the location. What I am interested in knowing is if it is possible to do this using just the name of the table.
